# Stuck in one page checkout payment information

Tags: magento-1.7, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

My problem is in onepage checkout, here it is :

- When I go to shipping method ,  checkout progress disappear and Error text appear .
- In payment information , i cant move to next step , it stuck in there . I tried both of two method . In payment method , i enable all of them .
- I open inspect element , in network tab , i see error : **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CACHE_MISS**

It said error in my Block , "Links" is my block to add link to top link , its have only 1 method , here it is :

```
<?php
class Atom_Rewardpoint_Block_Links extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
    public function addRewardpointLink()
    {
        $point=Mage::getModel("rewardpoint/customer")->load(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId())->getData('point_balance');
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        $text = 'My Points ( '.$point.' <img src= "'.$this->getSkinUrl("images/point.gif").'"/>'. ')';
        $position=1;

      // error line is method addLink  , i dont know what's wrong 

        $parentBlock->addLink(
                $text, 'rewardpoint/index/info', 'My Points',true,false,$position
            );

        return $this;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: I removed my top link block and check out ok .
In top link , i use $this->getParentBLock() to add "Mypoint" link . its work ok at other pages . i dont want to lose it . what should i do now ?

Answer (score 1):

The checkout progress is loaded via ajax calls, which means that only the specified blocks are loaded (and not the entire layout).

From the information you have supplied so far I can only understand that the `Rewardpoint_Links` block is loaded without a parent, and `$this->getParentBlock();` returns a `null` object.

You can modify the block and check to see if parent exists:

```
<?php
class Atom_Rewardpoint_Block_Links extends Mage_Core_Block_Template{
    public function addRewardpointLink()
    {
        $point=Mage::getModel("rewardpoint/customer")->load(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getId())->getData('point_balance');
        $parentBlock = $this->getParentBlock();
        $text = 'My Points ( '.$point.' <img src= "'.$this->getSkinUrl("images/point.gif").'"/>'. ')';
        $position=1;

      // error line is method addLink  , i dont know what's wrong 
        if($parentBlock) {
            $parentBlock->addLink(
                $text, 'rewardpoint/index/info', 'My Points', true, false, $position
            );
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much this will help but this exact broken checkout was started after I enabled following option, "`Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout`" on intimation by magento itself.

To disable it and repair checkout.do following :

```
Settings > Coniguration > Advanced + Admin > Security > Disable  "Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout"
```